# How to create locales like en_CA and fr_CA for the website that has many countries?

Tags: localization, middleman

In general when we talk about localization we mean en, ja, fr and so on...

Please look at http://www.siselean.com/ and click on the **Select Market** vertical button located on the left side of the page.

Countries are listed. When you click on any of them, each at least has 2 languages. 
Also pay attention to when you select a language, in the address bar it shows its respective locale such as http://www.siselean.com/**?locale=fr_CA**

If you click on Canada, for example, it has French and English versions of the page.

Here at http://middlemanapp.com/advanced/localization/ it's showing the classic way:

**locales/en.yml:**

```
en:
  hello: "Hello"
```

**locales/es.yml:**

```
es:
  hello: "Hola"
```

**The question is how to create locales en_CA and fr_CA in this case?**

Answer (score 1):

Middleman's i18n engine only works with lanugages, not countries.

For a menu, you will have to create a custom helper and/or partial that maps your languages to country-language pairs.

For custom URLs, the [Middleman-Blog](https://github.com/middleman/middleman-blog) extension might come in handy. Be aware that its i18n configuration is [different](http://middlemanapp.com/basics/blogging/#locale-specific-articles-and-localization) from that of vanilla Middleman.

Middleman-Blog serves as a poor man's database engine. You can create per-country pages that share common layouts but different content and frontmatter.

You can also store stuff in Yaml [data](http://middlemanapp.com/advanced/local-data/), categorize it in country-language fashion and use a custom helper to retrieve it.